# Using multiple match criteria in SQL server merge

Tags: sql, sql-server

At this point of time Source Table and destination Table is having Three columns 'ID', 'ST' and 'ADD'. 'ADD' allows null

Using ***SQL Server merge*** statement in I want to put changes made in source Table to destination.
Requirement:

1. If ***ID*** is **available in source but not in target** then **insert** a new
   row in target
2. For any ***ID* available in both source and target**, if **only *ADD*** is
   **changes** in source then **insert** new row in target. i.e If *ADD* for
   *ID=2* changed twice, then we will be having three rows(original + two changes) for *ID=2* in target, as we are inserting new row every
   time
3. For any ***ID* available in both source and target**, if **only *ST*
   changes** in source then modified value of *ST* should be **updated** in
   all rows for matched *ID* in target
4. For **any *ID* available in both source and target**, if **both *ST* and
   *ADD* changes** in source, then new row should be **inserted** for new *ADD* and all old rows should updated for that *ID* with **updated** value of *ST*

Can I achieve this with SQL Server merge? If not, what are the alternatives we have?

Comment: As far as I know, `MERGE` can only give you `when match` and `when not match`, meaning it can only distinguish between 1 and the rest, but can't distinguish between 2, 3, or 4.

Comment: It could be possible, do you have any primary key defined on target table. Do you want ST column to be unique ?

Comment: @BHouse In source table 'ID' is primary key. It works with it because information is only updated in source table. As we want to insert multiple records for same 'ID' in target, target table will be having separate column as primary key i.e. 'TargetID'. Also ST is not unique. It will be having values either 'A' or 'I'.

Answer (score 0):

Try merge with st as unique column and update id, add columns with multiple records

```
MERGE Tablex AS TARGET
USING Vw_tablex AS SOURCE
    ON (TARGET.id = SOURCE.id)
WHEN MATCHED
    AND
    --updates only St column as unique
    target.st <> source.st
    THEN
        UPDATE
        SET
            --- Inserts/updates multiple values in add column 
            TARGET.id = SOURCE.id
            ,TARGET.ADD = Source.ADD
            ,TARGET.st = SOURCE.st
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN
        INSERT (
            id
            ,ADD
            ,st
            )
        VALUES (
            SOURCE.id
            ,source.ADD
            ,source.st
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

`MERGE` needs primary key, you have to join two tables in such a way that rows are matched one-to-one. Otherwise you'll get an error similar to this:

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more
>   than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source
>   row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target
>   table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row
>   matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group
>   the source rows.

Your second requirement essentially means that the key consists of two columns `(ID, ADD)` and the `MERGE` statement should join on both columns:

```
MERGE INTO DstTable AS Dst
USING
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,ST
        ,ADD
    FROM SrcTable
) AS Src 
ON  Dst.ID = Src.ID
AND Dst.ADD = Src.ADD
WHEN MATCHED AND Dst.ST <> Src.ST THEN
UPDATE SET
    Dst.ST = Src.ST
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT
    (ID
    ,ST
    ,ADD)
VALUES
    (ID
    ,ST
    ,ADD)
;
```

This query does almost what you want. Updating of `ST` values is not quite as you described.

> 3. For any ID available in both source and target, if only ST changes in
>      source then modified value of ST should be updated in all rows for
>      matched ID in target

Since the query above joins on `(ID, ADD)`, the modified value of `ST` would be updated not in all rows for matched `ID` in target, but in one row with matched `ID` **and** `ADD`.

Similarly, the fourth requirement is not quite as you wanted. The new row will be inserted, but none of the old rows with the same `ID` would be updated.

For this kind of updates of `ST` you'll need a separate `UPDATE` statement. Or separate `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements without `MERGE` at all.